# put string and character in ofstream

Tags: c++, file, makefile

I want to put string and character together in `ofstream()` but I get error I want to create files in different names but in same path for example like this `E://string.txt` but string is variable
can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ofstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string filename;
  ofstream note("E://"filename".txt",ios::app);
}
```

Can you get my point?
I know my code is wrong but help me fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form your path with a `stringstream`, then extract a C-string out of that stream when you need it for constructing the `ofstream`:

```
std::stringstream path;
path << "E:/" << foo() << ".txt";

std::ofstream ofs(path.str().c_str());
```

If you only need to concatenate strings and characters, you can probably get by without the stream (which we've used above for its formatting features):

```
const std::string path = "E:/" + foo() + ".txt";
std::ofstream ofs(path.c_str());
```

In C++03, the `ofstream` constructor requires a C-string (`.c_str()`) for historical reasons, though this is fixed in C++11:

```
const std::string path = "E:/" + foo() + ".txt";
std::ofstream ofs(path);
```

---

Using your new example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
  string filename;
  ofstream note(("E:/" + filename + ".txt").c_str(), ios::app);
}
```

Comment: Change that to `<fstream>` not `<ofstream>`. :)